# EditText & onFocusChangeListener

Tags: android

1st of all I wanna thank you all for your great help. I'm a newby and stackoverflow answered most of my questions with already existing answers :-)

For my current project I want to create a kind of a calendar entry and the user has to set a date and time for this entry.
I decided to have EditText and want to open the picker @OnFocus on EditText (I know about the discussions if this makes sense or not but I think it makes sense to do so).

I have two issues now:
1) I don't get the OnFocusListener to work :-(
2) The time picker is always am/pm format though in the EditText it writes 24h format. My device is set to 24h and I don't get the time picker to use 24h, dependent on the device settings. I know it can be set to always be 24h but I think this is confusing for other countries not using 24h so it should be device setting dependent.

I hope you can help me and fix my hopefully not so messy code.
Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
public class Test extends ActionBarActivity implements OnFocusChangeListener {

EditText editText, txtDate, txtTime;
Button button, btnDate;

// Variable for storing current date and time
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new  PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

// Force keyboard to open as request focus doesn’t open keyboard
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

// Date & Time Picker Stuff
 txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
    txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTime);

    txtDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener());
    txtTime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener());

}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if (v == txtDate) {

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in edit text
                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
    }
    if (v == txtTime) {

        // Process to get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                            int minute) {
                        // Display Selected time in edit text
                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        tpd.show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Change `setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener());` to `setOnFocusChangeListener(this);` to hook your `EditTexts` up to the method you defined.

Comment: Great, that fixes the onFocusChange, such a tiny thingy making me struggle. Thanks a lot myanimal

Comment: Now I hope that somebody knows a solution for the am/pm - 24h issue ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix focus listener issue:

Change `setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener());` to `setOnFocusChangeListener(this);` to hook your `EditTexts` up to the method you defined.

A solution to 12 hour vs 24 hour display:

You can set the display to 24 hour if the system is set to 24 hour, or to 12 hour if the system is set to 12 hour formatting.

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

// ...

timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ActionBarActivity.this))
```

Comment: thanks again but I don't get it to work. I've set     TimePicker timePicker; and // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)); but it says contact cannot be resolved to a variable. Using "this" instead lety my app crash

Comment: my problem seems to be a more basic issue, please see my previous comment, edited during your fast answer

Comment: `context` needs to be an instance of the Android `Context` (activity, fragment, etc.). If you use `this` inside the listener it will reference the listener itself. To reference the containing activity you can try `ActionBarActivity.this`

Comment: thanks for your patience but unfortunaltely it doesn't work either with `timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ActionBarActivity.this))` after "// Launch Time Picker Dialog" but I get "No enclosing instance of the type ActionBarActivity is accessible in scope" and with context I get a null pointer exception

Comment: Sorry, I misread your class definition. That'll be `Test.this` - `Test` being the name of the Activity that this code executes in.

Comment: np, saw the typo and tried it already before, sorry for not mentioning it but I get there also the null pointer exception @ `is24HourFormat`

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to have another look at it in the morning.

Comment: The debugger suggests to change `timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ActionBarActivity.this))`to `timePicker.setIs24HourView(android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context));`but anyway calls that timePicker and context cannot be resolved

Comment: and for `timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(Test.this))`it says that timePicker and DateFormat can't be resolved as well as Test.this